# Show/Hide, SlideIn/Out, and FadeIn/Out not working - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't get my slidein/slideout and fadein/fadeout to work. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish...

1) For the 5K/10K events, when the user clicks on the picture use the
show/hide method to make the list of events appear and disappear.

2) For the Half Marathon events, when the user clicks on the picture use the
slideUp/slideDown method to make the list of events appear and
disappear.

3) For the Full Marathon events, when the user clicks on the picture use the
fadeIn/fadeOut method to make the list of events appear and disappear.

Also, I've tried to do these and cannot figure it out either...

4) Make all of the events listed under the pictures disappear before loading the
page. The lists should only appear when the user clicks on the picture.

5) Only one list of events can appear on the page at a time.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>FV Runners</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#5kpic").clickfunction(){
$("#5k").show().hide();
});

$("#halfpic").click(function(){
$("#half").slideup("slow").slidedown("slow");
});


$("#fullpic").click(function(){
$("#full").fadein("slow").fadeout("slow");
});
});


</script>

<body>

<div id="header">
<h1>Fox Valley Runners Club</h1>
</div> <!-- End of 'header' div-->

<div id="main">
</div>  <!-- End of 'main' div-->
<div id="pics">
<div class="race_box">
<img src="images/run1.jpg" id="5kpic" /><br />

<figcaption>5k/10k Events</figcaption>
<div class="races" id="5k">
<h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
<ul>
<li>Mini Sprint</br>10/30/17</br>Memorial Park</br>Appleton</li>
<li>Iron Horse</br>11/06/17</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
<li>Twilight Trail</br>11/13/17</br>River's Edge Park</br>Wrightstown</li>
</ul>
</div><!--  End of '5k' div-->
</div> <!-- End of 'run1' div-->

<div class="race_box">
<img src="images/run2.jpg" id="halfpic"/></button><br />
<figcaption>Half Marathon Events</figcaption>

<div class="races" id="half">
<h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
<ul>
<li>Fox River Marathon 10/15/17</br>Pierce Park</br>Appleton</li>
<li>N.E.W. Half Marathon 10/29/17</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
<li>Winnebago Run 11/27/17</br>Menominee Park</br>Oshkosh</li>
</ul>
</div> <!-- End of 'half' div-->
</div><!-- End of 'run2' div-->

<div class="race_box">
<img src="images/run3.jpg" id="fullpic"/><br />
<figcaption>Full Marathon Events</figcaption>

<div class="races" id="full">
<h3>Full Marathon Events</h3>
<ul>
<li>Cheesehead Marathon 9/24/17</br>Pamperin Park</br>Green Bay</li>
<li>Chain O'Lakes Marathon 10/29/17</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
<li>Fox Cities Marathon 11/12/17</br>Menominee Park</br>Oshkosh</li>
</ul>
</div> <!-- End of 'full' div-->
</div> <!-- End of 'run3' div-->

</div> <!-- End of 'pics' div-->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems listed below:

1. I changed `$("#5kpic").clickfunction(){` to `$("#5kpic").click(function(){`
2. I changed `</br>` to `<br/>`, the self closing tag
3. I moved the `<script>` to the bottom of the `<body>` tag so that `$(document).ready` is no longer necessary
4. I changed show/hide to `toggle`,
5. I changed slideup/slidedown to `slideToggle`
6. I changed fadein/fadeout to `fadeToggle`
7. I added css to hide the `.races` sections on page load

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>FV Runners</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    .races {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Fox Valley Runners Club</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="main"></div>

  <div id="pics">
    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/s45qt.png" id="5kpic" /><br />

      <figcaption>5k/10k Events</figcaption>
      <div class="races" id="5k">
        <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Mini Sprint<br/>10/30/17<br/>Memorial Park<br/>Appleton</li>
          <li>Iron Horse<br/>11/06/17<br/>Bay Beach Park<br/>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Twilight Trail<br/>11/13/17<br/>River's Edge Park<br/>Wrightstown</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUfvP.png" id="halfpic" /></button><br />
      <figcaption>Half Marathon Events</figcaption>

      <div class="races" id="half">
        <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Fox River Marathon 10/15/17<br/>Pierce Park<br/>Appleton</li>
          <li>N.E.W. Half Marathon 10/29/17<br/>Bay Beach Park<br/>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Winnebago Run 11/27/17<br/>Menominee Park<br/>Oshkosh</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="race_box">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSq0R.png" id="fullpic" /><br />
      <figcaption>Full Marathon Events</figcaption>

      <div class="races" id="full">
        <h3>Full Marathon Events</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Cheesehead Marathon 9/24/17<br/>Pamperin Park<br/>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Chain O'Lakes Marathon 10/29/17<br/>Bay Beach Park<br/>Green Bay</li>
          <li>Fox Cities Marathon 11/12/17<br/>Menominee Park<br/>Oshkosh</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#5kpic").click(function() {
      $("#5k").toggle();
    });

    $("#halfpic").click(function() {
      $("#half").slideToggle("slow");
    });


    $("#fullpic").click(function() {
      $("#full").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't have your images or css so I used running shoes.